# Modifying VBA so that transferring table to new sheet also carries over formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck. I developed this VBA which is working well, but needs a small modification.

This code doesn't transfer the color of the table into the new worksheet.

When I change `.Value` into something else I get an error.

```
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        'Make a new spreadsheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
    final_col = ws2.Cells(6, 250).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With ws
        'Paste data into new spreadsheet created above
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(8, final_col)).Value = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(5, 1), ws2.Cells(11, final_col)).Value
```

Comment: So you want to copy a range without formatting?

Comment: Yes, Should transfer like it is in original shape to new sheet.

Comment: If you want the color, you should Copy/Paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `xlPasteValues` as below

```
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        'Make a new spreadsheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
    final_col = ws2.Cells(6, 250).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(5, 1), ws2.Cells(11, final_col)).copy
    With ws
        'Paste data into new spreadsheet created above
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(8, final_col)).Value.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

This one will paste only value of your sheet and will not take care about format (background and so on..)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
final_col = ws2.Cells(6, 250).End(xlToLeft).Column
ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(5, 1), ws2.Cells(11, final_col)).Copy
With ws
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(8, final_col)).PasteSpecial
```

This solution work properly.